# Posting emdedded HTML and JavaScript to Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, model-view-controller

I know how to post a message, etc. to a Facebook wall, but I want to post a custom HTML and JavaScript Facebook wall, and I want that HTML/JavaScript code to appear so users can use that from Facebook without leaving Facebook, like embedded YouTube videos I have seen this to be possible...

I use this to post to Facebook:

```
FacebookWebClient client = new FacebookWebClient();

// Post to user's wall
var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postparameters["message"] = "Hello world!";
postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
postparameters["link"] = "http://thisisalink.com;
postparameters["description"] = "This is a description";

var result = client.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

How do I do this?

Maybe something like

```
postparameters["html"] = "html  or view";
```

If it is not possible, how do I post [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) content with [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) parameters?

Comment: I don't think FB wil let you post script because of security issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to post custom HTML or JavaScript code into a Facebook post because of security issues.

But you can still customize a lot of stuff like the link and the image, if you want to add an action link next to "Like, comment".

Find a lot more about publishing a post in *[Core Concepts › Graph API › Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)*.

Answer (score 1):

> if it is not possible, how do I post SWF content with Flash parameters?

To post an [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) video, you will need to do some work.

First, create a page that the SWF videos lives on where you can specify Open Graph meta tags. Read 
more in *[The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)*.

Then you need to create a post with a link to that page with the Open Graph tags. Then use the "link" parameter of the post object to point to the SWF file.